# Products not appearing in the catalog - Reindex not adding records

Tags: magento2, product, category, category-products

When I add products to a category through the admin pages, the product is not showing up on the relevant category page.

Ive have searched for an answer for this extensively and carried out all the necassary checks:

product enabled
is in stock
has a positive quantity
is assigned to a store view
etc..

I have done this many times but now it has all stopped working.

This includes creating new products to add to categories and also adding existing products to other categories.

the product does not appear. This is after reindexing and clearing cache etc..

After looking in the database, i found the the Category ID - Product ID pair does not appear in the table `catalog_category_product_index_store1`.

After adding the necassary records to this table manually and then performing a reindex, the products have appeared in their categories.

I have a lot more products to add and this is not an ideal solution in the long term as i shouldnt be manually adding records to the database like this.

does anyone know what could cause this issue and if it is a known issue and if there is a possible patch to it?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on version 2.3 and up, and by any chance did you enable MSI? If yes probably stock is in a source not enabled for your website. This can also happen if you run MFTF tests, but not wait for them to finish.
Also you said you have reindexed, did you run reindex from cli `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`?

Comment: Hi Dimitar, thanks for your response. Yes everything i did was through CLI and im not sure what MSI is. we have 5 people currently developing this site, so it is possible that someone has enabled this. Could you please explain a little more? Thanks

Comment: Also, we are not on 2.3, we are currently on 2.2.4

Comment: Hi MSI is Multi Source Inventory, but it was introduced with 2.3, so can not be the issue here.

Comment: aah cheers. I have since noticed that the table catalog_category_product_index is being updated as it is supposed to but nothing is happening with catalog_category_product_index_store1